# Computation Chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a problem computing a Chen class. Let $C$ be the twisted cubic ($Im(\nu)$), where
$$ \nu: \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}} $$
defined as $\nu(s,t)=(s^3,s^2t,st^2,t^3)$. Now let $\mathcal{O}_C$ be the structure sheaf and consider the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_C(n)$. I have to compute $c_1(\mathcal{O}_C(1))$, where $c_1$ is the first Chern class. I know that $c_1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(1))=1$. How can I compute $c_1(\mathcal{O}_C(1))$?

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, since $c_1\bigl(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^3}(1)\bigr)$ is Poincaré dual to a hyperplane class $H$, the first Chern class of the restriction $\mathcal{O}_C(1)$ to $C$ is dual to a hyperplane section $C \cap H$, namely, $3$ times the positive generator of $H^2(C, \mathbf{Z})$.

(Note that it's technically imprecise to write "$c_1\bigl(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^3}(1)\bigr) = 1$", since the Chern class is a $2$-dimensional cohomology class. :)